# How to convert JTextField to String and String to JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

How to convert `JTextField` to String and String to `JTextField` in Java?

Comment: hire an alchemist ;-) Seriously: _convert_ is not what you want ...

Answer (score 15):

> how to convert JTextField to string
>   and string to JTextField in java

If you mean how to get and set String from jTextField then you can use following methods:

```
String str = jTextField.getText() // get string from jtextfield
```

and

```
jTextField.setText(str)  // set string to jtextfield
//or
new JTextField(str)     // set string to jtextfield
```

You should check JavaDoc for [JTextField](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html)

Answer (score 7):

```
// to string
String text = textField.getText();

// to JTextField
textField.setText(text);
```

You can also create a new text field: `new JTextField(text)`

Note that this is not *conversion*. You have two objects, where one has a property of the type of the other one, and you just set/get it.

Reference: [javadocs of `JTextField`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html)

Answer (score 4):

The `JTextField` offers a `getText()` and a `setText()` method - those are for getting and setting the content of the text field.

Answer (score 4):

`JTextField` allows us to `getText()` and `setText()` these are used to get and set the contents of the text field, for example.

```
text = texfield.getText();
```

hope this helps