# inserting jtextbox value and jradiobutton value to database

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to insert values from textboxes into the database but getting error `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: String or binary data would be truncated`. I thought the problem was with radio button but when I tried to insert value in the database removing radio button and gender from the query, I am getting the same error.

I tried inserting values `Name: a, Username:a ,Contact:a , radio button [male]`, still getting the same error.
I can not find out how I am getting this error.

```
create table temp (
  id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(32) not null,
  username varchar(32) not null,  
  contact varchar(32) not null,
  gender int
);

btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try
                {
                    int gender = 0;
                    Connection sqlCon = DB_con.getSQLConnection();
                    PreparedStatement ps = sqlCon.prepareStatement(
                            "insert into temp (name, username, contact, gender) values ( ?, ?, ?, ?)"
                            );
                    ps.setString(1, txtName.toString());
                    ps.setString(2, txtUserName.toString());
                    ps.setString(3, txtContact.toString());

                    gender = (rbtnMale.isSelected()) ? 1 :2;
                    System.out.println("value of gender " + gender );
                    ps.setInt(4, gender);
                    int i = ps.executeUpdate();
                    System.out.println("records inserted: "+i);
                    sqlCon.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: It sounds like one or more of your values is exceeded 32 characters

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've edited my post. Please see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that one of these:

- txtName.toString()
- txtUserName.toString()
- txtContact.toString()

...is longer then 32 characters. Why not log them somewhere before you do the insert so you can see?

It's not clear what class these objects are from your code snippet. Is it possible that they're the default toString() method implementation of JTextField? If so, use [getText(), not toString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907338/how-to-convert-jtextfield-to-string-and-string-to-jtextfield).

Comment: Thank You very much. As you said I changed the toString() to getText(). It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
ps.setString(1, txtName.toString());
ps.setString(2, txtUserName.toString());
ps.setString(3, txtContact.toString());
```

to

```
ps.setString(1, txtName.getText());
ps.setString(2, txtUserName.getText());
ps.setString(3, txtContact.getText());
```

`toString` is doing a debug dump of the controls, which definitely longer than `32` characters and doesn't represent the text typed into the field (or at least not in a format you want ;))